# Groovy "except" syntax?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am a total Groovy newbie. I saw the following code [here](http://docs.huihoo.com/grails/1.0.3/ref/Controllers/beforeInterceptor.html).

```
def beforeInterceptor = [action:this.&auth,except:'login']
```

How would I expand this to also include a second exception, say, if the action was 'login2'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, would have expected a quick answer on this!

Well, found my own answer: you can't have more than one exception with except.

See the [feature request](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-92) here.

Instead, they recommend creating a Filter. [See here](http://docs.huihoo.com/grails/1.0.3/guide/single.html#6.1.5+Controller+Interceptors).

Comment: Not a ton of Groovy ninjas on the site yet (I'm just a newb myself) so some of these questions do take a while to get answered.  glad you solved it though!